# Why is blkdiscard not erasing all data of the whole drive?

Tags: hardware, ssd, sata, hdparm, trim

I have an old mSATA SSD (model name: Plextor PX-128M6M), which is installed to an mSATA-to-USB enclosure with ASM1153E controller.

I want to *(just logically, at the SSD controller level)* erase all of its data.

However, it seemed that:

1. `blkdiscard` command does not actually erase all requested region of data, just the beginning 2GiB minus 32KiB of data was actually erased.
2. `hdparm --trim-sector-ranges-stdin` seems to work fine, however, the SSD controller *(of this model of SSD specifically, another model does not seem to behave like this)* seems to be protecting the first 8 sectors (4KiB of data) from being erased by `TRIM` command.

---

My attempts and experiments are as follows:

1. I was doing this under Ubuntu 23.04.
2. Thanks to the guides from Arch Wiki, I found that I have to set `/sys/block/sdX/device/scsi_disk/*/provisioning_mode` to `unmap` first. It was `full` initially. After that, I thought the system was then able to send SCSI `UNMAP` command (through UASP, translated into `TRIM` command by the controller) to the old SSD.
3. I then did this to the whole drive: `blkdiscard -f -v /dev/sdX` (`sdX` is the actual device name), it then reported that all bytes (matches with the disk capacity) was discarded (erased), however I found that both the main GPT and the backup GPT at the beginning/end of disk space were still not erased.
4. I created a partition sized 2GiB, and then filled it with random data drained from `/dev/urandom`.
5. `blkdiscard -f -v /dev/sdX` was done on the whole drive, `hexdump` then showed that the last 1MiB + 32KiB of the first partiton was not erased (the partition starts from LBA 2048, with a sector size of 512 Bytes).
6. After re-executing `blkdiscard -f -v /dev/sdX1` on the new partition instead of the whole drive, `hexdump` showed that the last 32KiB of this partition was not erased.
7. I then tried `hdparm --trim-sector-ranges-stdin`, with a list of all sectors of the whole drive fed from stdin. This time the main GPT still stood, but all remaining data was erased to zero.
8. I filled the first 2048 sectors with `/dev/urandom` data. Then `hdparm --trim-sector-ranges-stdin` seemed to erase all data except the first 8 sectors (4KiB of data).

---

To confirm that the behavoir of first 8 sectors not being erased is enforced by the SSD controller instead of mSATA-to-USB chip:

9. I then installed this old Plextor SSD as an internal mSATA drive without USB enclosure. The first 8 sectors still survived after `hdparm --trim-sector-ranges-stdin`.
10. I have another newer Kingston-branded mSATA SSD. I tested it with `hdparm --trim-sector-ranges-stdin`, but all sectors went zero without one single exception, no matter it's USB-enclosed or directly installed as an internal drive.

Comment: Make sure you set `/sys/block/sdX/queue/discard_max_bytes` to `2147450880` when you have to manually change `provisioning_mode`. And you might still need `-p 2147450880` in `blkdiscard` if the drive also have TRIM alignment/granularity requirement (due to how the kernel split discard request). There's probably nothing you can do about the first-4K-problem.

Comment: @TomYan thanks. it seems that `-p $((2*1024*1024-32*1024))` worked. Setting `discard_max_bytes` changed some bit, but it still seems to leave the last 4KiB of 4GiB not trimmed (zeroed). btw I also wonder if this is a hardware issue (bc `discard_max_hw_bytes` actually reports 4GiB-512Bytes)? and if there's some generic way to avoid this (like, for other people, instead of specifically fix problem for myself only)?

Comment: When you have to change `provisioning_mode` manually, `discard_max_hw_bytes` is just a fake number. SATA SSD always have a TRIM limit of a multiple of 65535*64 logical blocks due to how the DSM/TRIM command is designed. (`2147450880` assumes logical block size of 512 bytes). `if there's some generic way` there's nothing else you can set to affect the discard request size at different level. If you can't "wipe" the whole drive with the `-p` trick, then your drive has a partial/broken "read zero after trim" implementation (which is not required by spec anyway).

Comment: for the record I've seen drive that requires the TRIM ranges to be 4K rounded (i.e., each TRIM range needs to be 65528), and still have the same problem like yours where some beginning/ending blocks of a drive can't be "TRIM-wiped".

Comment: Assuming your drive does NOT actually have requirement on TRIM range size, but requires each whole TRIM payload to be e.g. 64KiB aligned, then you might need `-p $((65534*512*64))`. You'll have to test yourself (with sufficient random filling each time). For the record, you don't even need to set `discard_max_bytes` if you use `-p`. `discard_max_bytes` only matters when each discard request is larger / cannot be controlled (i.e. fstrim). Also there will still be fragments since the kernel will first split request into 0xffffffff ones, which will in turn be split as per the max bytes value.

Comment: The biggest reason is set `discard_max_bytes` is that some drive / USB-bridge will hang or so if it receive a TRIM request that is larger than 65535*64*512 bytes. So it's mainly used to guarantee fstrim / discard mount option set to on doesn't make your drive hang.